# How to show dinamically listview selected item on some other page element in php

Tags: php, function, listview, selecteditem

Please help,

I have populated listview control from mdb database, but I can not dinamically call php function and show list item properties onclick or keypress event on some other page element. I suppose that I have to use combination of innset command, javascript function or something similar, but how exactly in my case?

My current php code is:

```
<?php
$db = 'C:\wamp64\www\MushroomsPHP\files\Mushrooms.mdb';
$sqlOpis = "SELECT * FROM SveGljiveByRod";
if(!file_exists($db)){
    die('Error finding access database');
}
$content=access_result_opis($db,$sqlOpis);
        
function access_result_opis($db,$sqlOpis){
    try{
        if(!file_exists($db)){
            throw new RuntimeException('Access Database file path is incorrect or file does not exist.');
        }
        try{
            $cnnt_str="odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=".$db.";Uid=; Pwd=;";
            $db = new PDO($cnnt_str);
            $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        }
        catch (exception $e){
            print_r($e,true);
            $content["error_flag"]="true";
            $content["error_mesg"]="access connection error ". $e->getMessage();
            return $content;
        }
    //run the query 
    try{
        $result=$db->query($sqlOpis);
        $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
        catch (exception $e){
            $content["error_flag"]="true";
            $err=$db->errorInfo();
            $content["error_mesg"]="access query error ".$e->getMessage();
            return $content;
        }
        // Listview
        echo '<p>List of mushrooms</p>';
        echo '<select id="mylist" name="myname" size=40 >';
        $rowcount=0;
        $st=0;
        foreach ($result as $row ) {
            $rowcount++;
            if ($rowcount==1){
                echo '<option onclick="' . item_describe($row["Latin"]) . '" value="Option ' . $rowcount . '" selected>' . $row["Latin"] . '</option>';
            } else {
                echo '<option onclick="' . item_describe($row["Latin"]) . '" value="Option ' . $rowcount . '">' . $row["Latin"] . '</option>';
            }
        }
        echo "</select>";
        echo "<p>Number of items: " . $rowcount . "</p>";
        $st=1;
    }
    catch (exception $e){
        $content["error_flag"]="true";
        $content["error_mesg"]="fetch$row error ".print_r($e,true);
        return $content;
    } 
}
?>

<?php
function item_describe($latname){   
    if ($st==1){
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            if ($row["Latin"]==$latname){
                echo $row["Latin"];
                echo "some text";                       
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

?>